# ProFTPD fail : UserPassword Missing argument

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, xampp, proftpd

I am new to php . I am unable to start to Proftpd in xampp . I am using ubuntu 64bit .few days back its work properly , but now it is not working

```
**Error Message of Lampp:**
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startftp
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
Contents of "/opt/lampp/var/proftpd/start.err":
dineshkumar-desktop proftpd[5108]: Fatal: UserPassword: missing arguments on line 43 of '/opt/lampp/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

**Here is my proftpd.cong file:**

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to 
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "daemon" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName          "ProFTPD"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21
# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User daemon
#Group daemon

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/*>
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>

# only for the web servers content
DefaultRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs

<Limit SITE_CHMOD>                                                                                                                                                         
  DenyAll                                                                                                                                                                  
</Limit>  

# daemon gets the password "xampp"
# commented out by xampp security
#UserPassword daemon 2TgxE8g184G9c
UserPassword  daemon
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_mysql.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
w97KTswgQ8VI.

# daemon is no normal user so we have to allow users with no real shell
RequireValidShell off

# daemon may be in /etc/ftpusers so we also have to ignore this file
UseFtpUsers off
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the line which starts with : 
"Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ..."
and then put the "UserPassword  daemon" part and the password on one line, just like the syntax of the previous line.

By the way. It makes sense to change your passwords if this is used outside of your local LAN.